# The Fundemental Group Generated By Six Elements

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I'm reading out of "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology" by Bott and Tu. In the introductory chapter they define the fundamental group. I understood their definition until they claim the following:

> $\pi_1\left(X,p\right)$ is generated by six elements $\left\{x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3\right\}$ subject to the single relation 
>   $$\prod_{i=1}^3 \left[x_i,y_i\right] =1 $$ 
>   Where $\left[x_i,y_i\right]$ is the commutator $x_iy_ix_i^{-1}y_i^{-1}$ and 1 is the identity.

I struggle to see how this is true. Is there a proof of this somewhere that I can read or is there a simple fact that I'm overlooking?

Comment: This is not true for general fundamental groups; it is very likely that the fundamental group of a specific space is being computed here.

Comment: Probably $X$ here is a three-holed torus and the $x_i, y_i$ are the standard generators.

Comment: Just before they bring up the specific case of a Riemann surface of genus 3. Is this fact true for those surfaces?

Comment: Google [Fundamental group of compact Riemann surface of genus $g$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136331/the-fundamental-group-of-a-closed-surface-without-classification-of-surfaces).